# Why does using char agrv instead of char **argv as the argument of main cause the following output?

Tags: c++, c, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

When I do this:

```
int main(int agrc, char argv)
{
    printf("%d", argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this input when I run the program from command line:

```
$ prog_name 0
0

$ prog_name (from 0-7 characters)
48

$ prog_name 12345678
56

$ prog_name 1234567812345678
64

// and so on...
```

So where do these values come from and why they increment by 8?

What happens when I have this instead:

```
int main(int agrc, char argv[])
```

?

Comment: `gcc filename.c -Wall -o obj` Doesn't your compile throw any warning or error. The valid prototype for `main()` is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or 
`int main(void)`.. Let me not bring the other valid one which migiht confuse you for now

Comment: That is not a valid signature for `main` so the result is undefined behavior.

Comment: The operators are not just for decoration or that the code looks more mythical. Reading a book on programming in C will answer that question clearly.

Comment: @Olaf yes I understand what those operators do, but I didn't understand why I get that output.
As Captain Oblivious  pointed out I now understand that the behavior of this is unpredictable.

I thought I would get some sort of error with gcc, but I only got a warning.

Comment: @Olaf Understanding those operators and understanding the result of ignoring the requirements placed on `main` are two different things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Capt'n: I drew back my comment as it did not state clear it is my opinion.I actually think knowing about pointer/array, and using wrong argument types results in UB is vital knowledge to program in C. That is one of the first things I tell my students. But that's me, other tutors or ressources might put less emphasis on such issues.

Answer (score 5):

Your output is likely to be an address of "ordinary" `argv` parameter, that is <strike>implicitely converted</strike> interpreted<sub>[see comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954699/why-does-using-char-agrv-instead-of-char-argv-as-the-argument-of-main-cause-th/30954898?noredirect=1#comment49947365_30954898)</sub> as `char`. In other words I suspect that what you have is equivalent to:

```
int main(int agrc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%d", (char) argv);
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine (CentOS 6 32-bit) disassembled object codes are as follows:

```
   0x080483c4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483c5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483c7 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080483ca <+6>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x080483cd <+9>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x080483d0 <+12>:    movsbl %al,%eax
   0x080483d3 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x080483d7 <+19>:    movl   $0x80484b4,(%esp)
   0x080483de <+26>:    call   0x80482f4 <printf@plt>
```

and original code that you've posted:

```
   0x080483c4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483c5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483c7 <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x080483ca <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x080483cd <+9>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x080483d0 <+12>:    mov    %al,0x1c(%esp)
   0x080483d4 <+16>:    movsbl 0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x080483d9 <+21>:    mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
   0x080483dd <+25>:    movl   $0x80484b4,(%esp)
   0x080483e4 <+32>:    call   0x80482f4 <printf@plt>
```

In both cases `$0x80484b4` stores `"%d"` format specifier as string literal and `0xc(%ebp)` is responsible for actual value that is used by `printf()`:

```
(gdb) x/db 0xbffff324
0xbffff324: -60
(gdb) p $al
$3 = -60
```

Notice that `AL` (one byte accumulator, i.e. part of `EAX`) "fetches" only the first byte (my CPU is little endian, so it's actually LSB) at `$ebp+0xc` address. This means that `(char)` conversion does "cut-off" of an `argv` address.

As a consequence you may observe that each of these numbers have `log2(n)` least significant bits unset. This due to *alignment* requirement for objects of pointer type. Typically for a 32-bit x86 machine `alignof(char **) == 4`.

As already pointed in comments you violated C Standard, so it's an example of UB.

Comment: I would have thought it more likely to be a byte-wise reinterpretation, not a logical conversion? This may especially make a difference since `sizeof(char**)` and `sizeof(char)` are unlikely to be the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I checked it by examining various input with  `gdb` sessions, but I am not 100%  sure. This is all implemenentation-depedendent.

Comment: Of course it's implementation-dependent. It's a question about what the implementation is doing. (OP should specify which impl though)

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit What info exactly should I post?
I use MiniGW on Windows 7 (64bit) GCC version: 4.8.1

Comment: For OP's code , I get: `-12`, `100`, `-124`, `-28`, `-108`, `4`, `-76`, `84`, `68`, `-12`, `-44`, `20`, `52` across multiple runs for executing the *same binary* with `./a.out 12345678`. My platform is Linux (built on a custom kernel from the Linux source tree 3.19) and using gcc 5.1.1 and glibc 2.21. I hope I have given enough *implementation details* for anyone cares to explain.

Comment: @Firmus: Also your processor details (BTW it's called "MinGW", not "MiniGW" lol :P)

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: Nice :) +1

Comment: This is not a conversion, implicit or otherwise (and there is no implicit conversion from `char**` to `char`). Most likely the `char**` value that's actually passed to `main` is interpreted as a `char` value, or part of it is. Or, depending on the implementation, some uninitialized memory location might be interpreted as a `char` value, if `char` and `char**` are passed differently as argument.

Answer (score -1):

From the C standards, regarding the signature of `main()`

> The implementation declares no prototype for this function.

So, there will be no issues from the compiler if you pass different type of arguments.

In your code,

```
int main(int agrc, char argv)
```

is not the signature recommended for `main()`. It should either be

```
int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
```

or, at least

```
int main(int agrc, char** argv)
```

Otherwise, in a hosted environment, the behavior in not defined. You can check more on this in `C11` standard, chapter 5.1.2.2.1.

In your case, as you see, you are making the second parameter a `char` type. As per the standard specification,

> If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings,....

So, here, the supplied `0` is passed to `main()` as a pointer to *string* which is accepted in a `char`, which is not a defined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, he knows. He wanted us to explain the output he got from an implementation perspective. You did not answer the question. -1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't think so. If i know I am replacing a `char * []` with a `char` and asking why it gives weird output...then....

Comment: He's not asking why it gives weird output. He's asking why it gives _this_ output. "Since the compiler doesn't give me an error, where do these numbers come from?"

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit is right... I did that out of curiosity and I noticed the pattern. I thought there was a particular reason for this behavior ... F*ck me, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I updated. Please review?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: No, you're still not getting it. _"It's not a defined behaviour"_ is your answer. Well, damn, _he knows that_. But the implementation and the runtime are still doing something that results in these values and, whether that behaviour is well-defined by any language standard or not, this OP would like to know what that "something" is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I really don't understand now. So basically OP is asking to define the UB, right? Sorry, that is out of my knowledge, I don't have compiler specific idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I would, but I am not reading the question the way you do. So...peace. :-)

Comment: also, tagging both `C` and `C++`, writing `Why does omitting * and [] `...that makes me doubtful that `Yeah, he knows. He wanted us to explain the output he got from an implementation perspective.` That is rather a random experiment, with the good (or ugly) looking `*` and `[]`s.

Answer (score -3):

There is a string pointer on the stack, but you declared `main` with a char there, and then printed it as a decimal.  The memory address of that string is not predictable, so you get unpredictable output.

Try this:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    printf( "%s", argv[1] );
    return 0;
}
```

I think that will give you what you intended.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The poster wants to know why they get the result they do, not how to properly define `main`.

Comment: Based on his reputation, I inferred that he really wanted it to just work, so I provided that.  However, I have also edited the answer to address his literal question.

Comment: Sorry, no, you didn't.

Comment: What part of `The memory address of that string is not predictable` do you not understand?  It says where the values come from and that there is not a deterministic reason to increment by 8.